# Use ActiveMQ in Travis CI

Tags: spring, spring-mvc, activemq-classic, travis-ci

My [build](https://travis-ci.org/zjhzxhz/voj/jobs/62875115) in Travis CI failed after add configuration on Active MQ.

The log of Travis CI shows:

```
Caused by: javax.jms.JMSException: Could not connect to broker URL: tcp://localhost:61616. Reason: java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused
    at org.apache.activemq.util.JMSExceptionSupport.create(JMSExceptionSupport.java:36)
    at org.apache.activemq.ActiveMQConnectionFactory.createActiveMQConnection(ActiveMQConnectionFactory.java:360)
    at org.apache.activemq.ActiveMQConnectionFactory.createActiveMQConnection(ActiveMQConnectionFactory.java:305)
    at org.apache.activemq.ActiveMQConnectionFactory.createConnection(ActiveMQConnectionFactory.java:245)
    at org.springframework.jms.connection.SingleConnectionFactory.doCreateConnection(SingleConnectionFactory.java:365)
    at org.springframework.jms.connection.SingleConnectionFactory.initConnection(SingleConnectionFactory.java:305)
    at org.springframework.jms.connection.SingleConnectionFactory.getConnection(SingleConnectionFactory.java:283)
    at org.springframework.jms.connection.SingleConnectionFactory.createConnection(SingleConnectionFactory.java:224)
    at org.springframework.jms.support.JmsAccessor.createConnection(JmsAccessor.java:180)
    at org.springframework.jms.listener.AbstractJmsListeningContainer.createSharedConnection(AbstractJmsListeningContainer.java:413)
    at org.springframework.jms.listener.AbstractJmsListeningContainer.establishSharedConnection(AbstractJmsListeningContainer.java:381)
    at org.springframework.jms.listener.AbstractJmsListeningContainer.doStart(AbstractJmsListeningContainer.java:285)
    at org.springframework.jms.listener.SimpleMessageListenerContainer.doStart(SimpleMessageListenerContainer.java:209)
    at org.springframework.jms.listener.AbstractJmsListeningContainer.start(AbstractJmsListeningContainer.java:270)
    ... 44 more
```

I'm using Spring MVC, here's the configuration for testing:

```
<beans "Some DTDs here">
    <!-- Base Components -->
    <context:annotation-config />
    <context:component-scan base-package="com.trunkshell.voj" />

    <!-- Some other configuration for JDBC and other service -->

    <!-- Message Service -->
    <bean id="amqConnectionFactory" class="org.apache.activemq.ActiveMQConnectionFactory">
        <constructor-arg index="0" value="tcp://localhost:61616"/>
    </bean>
    <bean id="connectionFactory" class="org.springframework.jms.connection.CachingConnectionFactory">
        <constructor-arg ref="amqConnectionFactory" />
    </bean> 
    <bean id="defaultDestination" class="org.apache.activemq.command.ActiveMQQueue">
        <constructor-arg index="0" value="vojMessageQueue"/>
    </bean>     
    <bean id="jmsTemplate" class="org.springframework.jms.core.JmsTemplate">
        <property name="connectionFactory" ref="connectionFactory" />
        <property name="defaultDestination" ref="defaultDestination" />
    </bean>
    <bean class="org.springframework.jms.listener.SimpleMessageListenerContainer">
        <property name="connectionFactory" ref="connectionFactory" />
        <property name="destinationName" value="vojMessageQueue" />
        <property name="messageListener" ref="messageReceiver" />
    </bean> 
    <bean id="messageSender" class="com.trunkshell.voj.util.MessageSender"></bean>
    <bean id="messageReceiver" class="com.trunkshell.voj.util.MessageReceiver"></bean>
</beans>
```

I also noticed that Travis CI only support RabbitMQ and ZeroMQ.
Here's the reference: [link](http://docs.travis-ci.com/user/ci-environment/#Messaging-Technology)

So what should I do to fix the error in Travis CI?

Or how to skip this problem in Travis CI.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't see that you actually start an ActiveMQ broker at port 61616. Either, do that, or preferably use the VM transport during the integration tests. I.e. change `tcp://localhost:61616` to `vm://localhost?broker.persistent=false`

Of course, you have to be able to change that ActiveMQ URL when you deploy to a production environment. Maybe you can use spring property placeholders?